# Simplex method: Optimal solution for a minimization problem given parameters?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, simplex

Given a minimization problem with a cost function:
$3x_1 + x_2 + \beta x_3 + \alpha x_4$

Under the constraints:
$$2x_1 + \frac{1}{2}x_2 + 5x_3 + \frac{1}{2}x_4 = 7\\
3x_1 + \frac{1}{2}x_2 +x_3 -\frac{1}{2}x_4 = \gamma\\
\overline x \geq 0$$

I want to find out what values of the parameters $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ make it such that the basis ${2,4}$ is an optimal solution.

For the basis ${2,4}$ to be a feasible solution, I got that $-7 \leq \gamma \leq 7$, and then I tried going over all the possible neighbors of ${2,4}$ and checking to see which parameters cause the objective function to be non-increasing, but I got stuck.

I feel as if I'm missing something here, but I'm not sure what.

Any help would be welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just to impose that the basis
$$B=\begin{pmatrix} 1/2 & 1/2\\ 1/2 & -1/2\end{pmatrix}$$
is primal-feasible, that is
$$B^{-1} b \geq 0$$
and dual-feasible, that is
$$c^{\top} - c_B^{\top}B^{-1}A \geq 0$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. Why is it not enough to check that $c$ is non-negative for all indexes not in $B$?